# How to hide the null item option in appmaker radio group when allowNull=true and field is boolean?

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a boolean field for which I am using a radio group for which allowNull=true and no default value has been set. It currently looks like the below

[image]

I want the same to look like below (as I don't want to show the null option)

[image]

Note: Want to achieve this without changing the allowNull value and also without setting default value to true or false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following to the **onAttach** event handler did the trick for me:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  var elem = widget.getElement();
  var children = elem.children[1];
  var grandChildren = children.children;
  var grandChild = grandChildren[0];
  grandChild.parentNode.removeChild(grandChild);
},100);
```